# ¿Cómo utilizar las propiedades de un objeto dentro de un switch en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código y comencé haciendo esto con el objetivo de crear un tarifario de diseño grafico en el que el cliente pueda ver precios y se realice el calculo del mismo dependiendo del tipo de cliente:

```
let nombreIngresado = prompt("Ingresá tu nombre");
let saludo = alert("Hola " + nombreIngresado + " bienvenid@ a mi web");

let aclaracionPrecios = alert("Te invito a descubrir los diferentes precios de este tarifario");

let categoriaProducto = prompt("Elegí la categoría que te interese:\n1) Branding \n2) Packaging \n3) Editoriales \n4) Redes Sociales");
console.log(parseInt(categoriaProducto));

switch (categoriaProducto) {
    case "1":
        let categoriaBranding = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Logo \n2) Identidad de marca \n3) Manual de marca \n4)Papelería corporativa");
        switch (categoriaBranding) {
            case "1":
                let precioLogo = alert("El precio es 2400");
                break;

            case "2":
                let precioIdentidad = alert("El precio es 6000");
                break;

            case "3":
                let precioManual = alert("El precio es 5000");
                break;

            case "4":
                let precioPapeleria = alert("El precio es 2500");
                break;

            default:
                console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
                break;
        }
        break;

    case "2":
        let categoriaPackaging = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Etiqueta \n2) Stickers");
        switch (categoriaPackaging) {
            case "1":
                let precioEtiqueta = alert("El precio es 1200");
                break;

            case "2":
                let precioStickers = alert("El precio es 450");
                break;

            default:
                console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
                break;
        }
        break;

    case "3":
        let categoriaEditoriales = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Folleto díptico \n2) Folleto tríptico \n3) Brochure (máx. 10 pág.) \n4) Afiche \n5) Aviso publicitario");
        switch (categoriaEditoriales) {
            case "1":
                let precioFolletoDip = alert("El precio es 1400");
                break;

            case "2":
                let precioFolletoTrip = alert("El precio es 1800");
                break;

            case "3":
                let precioBrochure = alert("El precio es 3000");
                break;

            case "4":
                let precioAfiche = alert("El precio es 2300");
                break;

            case "5":
                let precioAviso = alert("El precio es 500");

            default:
                console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
                break;
        }
        break;

    case "4":
        let categoriaRedes = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Diseño de feed \n2) Plantillas para posteos");
        switch (categoriaRedes) {
            case "1":
                let precioFeed = alert("El precio es 5500");
                break;

            case "2":
                let precioPlantillas = alert("El precio es 1000");
                break;

            default:
                console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
                break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
        break;
}

/* Calculo de precio de acuerdo al tipo de cliente.: tipo A o tipo B 
Cliente A: particulares, emprendimientos o empresas unipersonales. 
Cliente B: Empresas medianas, grandes u organismos estatales */

class Producto {
    constructor(nombre, precio, tipoCliente) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.tipoCliente;
    }

    calcularPrecioClienteA() {
        if (this.tipoCliente == "A") {
            return this.precio;
        } else {
            return this.precio * 4.5;
        }
    }
}

function crearProducto() {
let tipoCliente = prompt("Cliente A: particulares, emprendimientos o empresas unipersonales."/n,
                         "Cliente B: Empresas medianas, grandes u organismos estatales.")
let producto = new Producto(nombre, precio, tipoCliente)
return producto
```

}

Hasta allí todo bien, salvo que la función todavía no hacía nada y entonces intenté crear un objeto para utilizar sus propiedades dentro del switch y allí es donde llevo días tratando de entender su funcionamiento. Y he aquí el código donde no logro que funcione el prompt:

```
let nombreIngresado = prompt("Ingresá tu nombre");
alert("Hola " + nombreIngresado + " bienvenid@ a mi web");
alert("Te invito a descubrir los diferentes precios de este tarifario");

let categoriaProducto = prompt("Elegí la categoría que te interese:\n1) Branding \n2) Packaging \n3) Editoriales \n4) Redes Sociales");

let categoriaBranding, categoriaPackaging, categoriaEditoriales, categoriaRedes;

switch (categoriaProducto) {
    case "1":
        categoriaBranding = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Logo \n2) Identidad de marca \n3) Manual de marca \n4)Papelería corporativa");
        break;
    case "2":
        categoriaPackaging = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Etiqueta \n2) Stickers");
        break;
    case "3":
        categoriaEditoriales = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Folleto díptico \n2) Folleto tríptico \n3) Brochure (máx. 10 pág.) \n4) Afiche \n5) Aviso publicitario");
        break;
    case "4":
        categoriaRedes = prompt("Ingresá el producto que te interesa: \n1) Diseño de feed \n2) Plantillas para posteos");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
        break;
}

class Producto {
    constructor (nombre, precio, categoria){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.tipoCliente;
    }

    calcularPrecioClienteA() {
        if (this.tipoCliente == "A") {
            return this.precio;
        } else {
            return this.precio * 4.5;
        }
    }
}

function crearProducto () {
    let tipoCliente = prompt ("Tipo de cliente A: particulares, emprendimientos o empresas unipersonales.")
    let producto = new Producto(nombre, precio, categoria)
    producto.tipoCliente = tipoCliente
    return producto
}

let productosAgregados = 0;
while (productosAgregados < 11) {
    console.log("Agregaste " + productosAgregados + " productos al carrito");
    productosAgregados++;
}

let productoCreado = crearProducto();
```

La idea sería utilizar las propiedades de uno o varios objetos instanciados dentro del switch pero por mas que le doy vueltas no logro comprender como hacerlo (sin utilizar otros elementos de Javascript sino solo objetos y switch). De hecho funciona así como está pero surge un error por consola donde "nombre" no está definido en la instanciación del objeto y justo allí me explotó la cabeza.

Busqué en internet algo que me mostrara como aprovechar las propiedades de un objeto bajo la notación de clases dentro de un switch pero no pude o por lo menos quizás no supe como hacerlo.

Comment: Cuando creás tu objeto _Producto_ en la función _crearProducto_, ¿dónde están las variables _nombre_, _precio_ y _categoria_?

Comment: Procura adjuntar un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estás enfrentando con el mensaje de error "nombre no está definido" se debe a que en la función crearProducto, estás utilizando las variables nombre, precio y categoria para crear un nuevo objeto Producto, pero estas variables no están definidas en el alcance de la función.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Eliminar las variables categoriaBranding, categoriaPackaging, categoriaEditoriales y categoriaRedes, ya que no son necesarias en este punto del código.

Modificar la función crearProducto para que reciba los parámetros nombre, precio y categoria que se obtienen del switch y utilizarlos en la creación del objeto Producto.
```

aca te doy un ejemplo y como hacerlo:

```
    class Producto {
    constructor (nombre, precio, categoria){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.tipoCliente;
    }

    calcularPrecioClienteA() {
        if (this.tipoCliente == "A") {
            return this.precio;
        } else {
            return this.precio * 4.5;
        }
    }
}function crearProducto(nombre, precio, categoria) {
    let tipoCliente = prompt ("Tipo de cliente A: particulares, emprendimientos o empresas unipersonales.");
    let producto = new Producto(nombre, precio, categoria);
    producto.tipoCliente = tipoCliente;
    return producto;
}

// Resto del código que tienes ahi
```

Ahora, al llamar a la función crearProducto desde el switch, puedes pasarle los valores correctos para nombre, precio y categoria. Por ejemplo:

```
    let productoCreado;

switch (categoriaProducto) {
    case "1":
        productoCreado = crearProducto("Logo", 2400, "Branding");
        break;
    case "2":
        productoCreado = crearProducto("Etiqueta", 1200, "Packaging");
        break;
    case "3":
        productoCreado = crearProducto("Folleto díptico", 1400, "Editoriales");
        break;
    case "4":
        productoCreado = crearProducto("Diseño de feed", 5500, "Redes Sociales");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("El valor ingresado no es válido");
        break;
}

console.log(productoCreado);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".

Comment: No uses chatGPT... está [prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido) en este sitio...